# Implementing perspective transform using vips

Tags: opencv, go, vips

I am trying to implement a perspective transform using vips in Go. I am using opencv's `GetPerspectiveTransform` method to calculate a transform matrix then computing a map image as follows

```golang
func DistortPerspective(ref *vips.ImageRef, tiepoints []float64) {
    T := createTransform(tiepoints)

    // make an index image where pixels have the value of their (x, y) coordinates
    index, err := vips.XYZ(ref.Width(), ref.Height())
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }

    i0, err := index.Copy()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }
    i1, err := index.Copy()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }
    err = i0.ExtractBand(0, 1)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }
    err = i1.ExtractBand(1, 1)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }

    T00 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(0, 0))
    T01 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(0, 1))
    T02 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(0, 2))

    T10 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(1, 0))
    T11 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(1, 1))
    T12 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(1, 2))

    T20 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(2, 0))
    T21 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(2, 1))
    T22 := float64(T.GetFloatAt(2, 2))

    // i0 * T[0,0]
    i0xT00 := linear(i0, T00, 0)

    // i1 * T[0,1] + T[0,2]
    i1xT01_T02 := linear(i1, T01, T02)

    // i0 * T[1,0]
    i0xT10 := linear(i0, T10, 0)

    // i1 * T[1,1] + T[1,2]
    i1xT11_T12 := linear(i1, T11, T12)

    //i[0] * T[0,0] + i[1] * T[0,1] + T[0,2]
    i0xT00_i1xT01_T02 := add(i0xT00, i1xT01_T02)

    //i[0] * T[1,0] + i[1] * T[1,1] + T[1,2]
    i0xT10_i1xT11_T12 := add(i0xT10, i1xT11_T12)

    //i[0] * T[2,0]
    i0xT20 := linear(i0, T20, 0)

    //i[1] * T[2,1] + T[2,2]
    i1xT21_T22 := linear(i1, T21, T22)

    //i[0] * T[2,0] + i[1] * T[2,1] + T[2,2]
    i0xT20_i1xT21_T22 := add(i0xT20, i1xT21_T22)

    //x = (i[0] * T[0,0] + i[1] * T[0,1] + T[0,2]) / (i[0] * T[2,0] + i[1] * T[2,1] + T[2,2])
    x := divide(i0xT00_i1xT01_T02, i0xT20_i1xT21_T22)

    //y = (i[0] * T[1,0] + i[1] * T[1,1] + T[1,2]) / (i[0] * T[2,0] + i[1] * T[2,1] + T[2,2])
    y := divide(i0xT10_i1xT11_T12, i0xT20_i1xT21_T22)

    //# join up x and y as a map image
    mapimage := bandjoin(x, y)

    //transform the original image
    err = ref.Mapim(mapimage)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Debug(nil, err)
    }
}
```

However the image that comes as a result is wrong. I was using this Stack Overflow answer as a reference [How to perform perspective distort transformation in VIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202733/how-to-perform-perspective-distort-transformation-in-vips)
and it appeared to me that opencv `WarpPerspective` method does something similar so I thought that using opencv to calculate transform coefficients would work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was two-fold.

First of all, use `GetDoubleAt(row int, col int)` method that returns proper float64 instead of `GetFloatAt(row int, col int)`, that returns float32. Somehow the conversion was messing up the numbers.

Second of all, in the method for calculating the transform matrix, in the `GetPerspectiveTransform` call, source and destination sets should be flipped. That is because opencv's `WarpPerspective` method implicitly inverts the matrix, while this implementation does not.

```
func createTransform(distortion []float64) gocv.Mat {
    srcSet := []image.Point{
        {X: int(distortion[0]), Y: int(distortion[1])},
        {X: int(distortion[4]), Y: int(distortion[5])},
        {X: int(distortion[8]), Y: int(distortion[9])},
        {X: int(distortion[12]), Y: int(distortion[13])},
    }
    dstSet := []image.Point{
        {X: int(distortion[2]), Y: int(distortion[3])},
        {X: int(distortion[6]), Y: int(distortion[7])},
        {X: int(distortion[10]), Y: int(distortion[11])},
        {X: int(distortion[14]), Y: int(distortion[15])},
    }
    return gocv.GetPerspectiveTransform(dstSet, srcSet)
}
```